# Could not load file or assembly with identical setup of Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

VS 2019.
The issue I’m having is properly getting a build running of the current version (2.4) of a Solution.
I keep running into the error of

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 
'csMeriamDeviceFoundation.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

I have two versions of this solution, 2.0 and 2.4. 2.0 was retrieved from a coworker’s laptop and version 2.4 was downloaded through Microsoft team foundation server. I was able to get 2.0 to build with little issues but was unable to get 2.4 to build. I've compared the DLL files and they are identical. I’ve made sure the settings for each project are identical, unloaded and reloaded the projects and even removed and re-added projects. I also made sure that the references for each project are identical (picture).
The one last thing to note is that when attempting to publish a project in 2.4 just to see what would happen, I got the following error.  Again, this only happens with 2.4 and not with 2.0.

```
Failed to connect to ‘path' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site ‘path’.
The path 'path' does not exist or you do not have access. The specified path is invalid.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL5bi.png)

Comment: This error may be caused by insufficient permissions. Please try opening 2.4 after running Visual Studio with administrator rights. In addition, what changes have been made in the solution from 2.0 to 2.4, especially in terms of path modification? This information is of great significance to solving this issue.

Comment: I did try running it in admin mode to no avail.  I'm not sure on what changes have been made between versions, including path modifications. I've just been looking at the folder structures and they seem identical. I'm trying out https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies right now to try to see if I can trouble shoot the issue from there.

Answer (score 0):

turns out dependencies were missing from my project.
Using https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies detected what the missing DLL files were and is now able to be ran in debug.

Comment: Your answer is helpful! You can mark it so that it can help more people